# Creating CSV file using Aspen SQLplus

Tags: sqlplus, aspen

I have a query from IP21 data that I run at a set time each day using Aspen InfoPlus.21. I now want to use python to analyze this data daily. How can I edit my SQL query to write csv file instead of just the query.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way:

```
set output = 'C:\test.csv';   --Note this is relative to the IP21 server, not the client machine

for (select * from myTable) do
    write column1 || ',' || column2 || ',' || column3;
end

set output = default;

write 'All done';
```